# VBA Run Time Mode Multi

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I've problem with Run-time Error 1004. In the discription of error says that "Unable to get Mode_Mult property of Worksheet Function class"

This error occurs because there is not Mode_Multi value in the selected range. It is OK but I can not skip error with On error resume or goto command.

My Command line like

```
ws.Range("f8") = WorksheetFunction.Mode_Mult(Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(t, 6)))
```

Comment: `Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(t, 6))` Here your are using the current active worksheet. It might be a good idea to be a little more explicit on what worksheet you are talking about, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "skip" the error with an `On Error Resume Next` statement. Now `On Error Resume Next` is dangerous as it hides all kins of errors, so it should be avoided in most cases. However, it is perfectly okay if you just want to "catch" an expected error - but limit it to just the line that might fail.

The following piece of code should work for you - you just have to decide what you want to write into `F8` if the `Mode_Mult` fails:

```
Dim mm as Variant
mm = "(no mm value)"      ' Choose whatever you want if Mode_Mult fails.
On Error Resume Next      ' Allow code to continue if Mode_Mult fails.
mm = WorksheetFunction.Mode_Mult(Range(Cells(1, 6), Cells(t, 6)))
On Error GoTo 0           ' But if now something fails, throw an error again.
ws.Range("F8") = mm
```